# configure webpack to resolve _ as lodash index

Tags: javascript, webpack, lodash

Currently I am using lodash functions like

```
import { get } from 'lodash';

const a = get({}, path, null);
```

because If I use

```
_.get({}, path, null);
```

eslint throws `undefined` error and this import won't work for node.js code, is there a way to tell webpack to resolve 
`_.get()` to `import { get } from 'lodash'; get();` automatically?

I want to use this in multiple files without explicitly importing from lodash and would like webpack to resolve _ as lodash index during build and dev server runs

I read about resolve and externals options in webpack config but they don't seem to help out here.

Answer (score 2):

Try to import lodash like this - `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: I want to use this in multiple files without explicitly importing from lodash and would like webpack to resolve _ as lodash index during build and dev server runs

Comment: You can try including `resolve` paths in your webpack.config.js. Like: `resolve: { modules: [ "node_modules" ]  }`